# how do i see all the column names in my dataset using colnames function without getting an error message?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-import, r-colnames

The challenge i am facing here is that the name i used to save my dataframe cannot be found in the environment thereby making it difficult to see the column names of my dataset.
this is the code am trying to run:

> colnames(202308-cyclistic_trip)
> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'cyclistic_trip' not found

This what i tried:

> colnames(202308-cyclistic_trip)
> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'cyclistic_trip' not found

Comment: The issue is that you have chosen a non-syntactic name for your dataset, i.e. it starts with a digit. To use an object with a non-syntactic name you have to wrap the name in backticks, i.e. try `colnames(\`202308-cyclistic_trip\`)`

Comment: There must be duplicates of this question.